# How to cache image with universal image loader in android

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I use [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library for android:

I would like to cache image but now it is downloading everytime:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheOnDisk(true) 
    .build();


    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, iv, options);
```

How should i configure the options to cache the images to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try both of this code :

```
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .build();
```

I used both of them and the images are cached.

Comment: Please accept my answer if this solve your problem. Otherwise, let me know. I have used this library for quite long time :)